# Copy To Clipboard On Click With Pseudo Element Tooltips

Tags: javascript, css, copy, clipboard, pseudo-element

I am attempting to make a tooltip created with a pseudo element clickable to then run a function to copy to clipboard.

I have already tried adding in onClick inside of the CSS pseudo-element as well as within the span as an onClick.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("firstnamereflect");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
  padding: 4px;
}


/* Tooltip styling */

[data-tooltip]:before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


/* Dynamic horizontal centering */

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:before,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}


/* Tooltip arrow styling/placement */

[data-tooltip]:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}


/* Dynamic horizontal centering for the tooltip */

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}

[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
  top: 100%;
  border-width: 0 6px 6px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}


/* Show the tooltip when hovering */

[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  display: block;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <span onclick="myFunction()" data-tooltip="Copy" data-tooltip-position="bottom" id="firstnamereflect"></span> </div>
```

I expect that when I click on the Copy tooltip created by data-tooltip that it will run a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. I think you can just attach an event handler to the tool tip itself. Once the display is none, it'll not render to the user so nothing would happen if the user clicks in the space.

JS Code:

```
// attach an event handler that'll show the tooltip 
document.querySelector("#hoverText").onmouseover = () => {
  document.querySelector("#toolTip").style.display = "inline-block";
}

// attach an event handler that'll hide the tooltip 
document.querySelector("#hoverText").onmouseout = () => {
  document.querySelector("#toolTip").style.display = "none";
}

// attach the copy function
document.querySelector("#toolTip").onclick = copyToClipboard;
```

Comment: Sorry.  This is my first six months of coding part time.  I'm not understanding where you are getting #hoverText and #toolTip from.

Comment: @JasonMarsteller I apologize, I didn't use the ids that you used. I just a generic id to describe the hoverable text and the tooltip. You can replace the ids with the correct id element.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.  The coding community is so welcoming!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your script and made it work. `copyText.select();` only work with text boxes like input, textarea etc. You can retrieve the value from a div/span using [range](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html)

Change your function to

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("firstnamereflect").firstChild;
  var range = document.createRange();
  var endOffset = copyText.length;
  range.setStart(copyText, 0);
  range.setEnd(copyText, endOffset);
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  alert("Copied the text: " + range);
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("firstnamereflect").firstChild;
  var range = document.createRange();
  var endOffset = copyText.length;
  range.setStart(copyText, 0);
  range.setEnd(copyText, endOffset);
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  alert("Copied the text: " + range);
}
```

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
  padding: 4px;
}


/* Tooltip styling */

[data-tooltip]:before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


/* Dynamic horizontal centering */

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:before,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}


/* Tooltip arrow styling/placement */

[data-tooltip]:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}


/* Dynamic horizontal centering for the tooltip */

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}

[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
  top: 100%;
  border-width: 0 6px 6px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}


/* Show the tooltip when hovering */

[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  display: block;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <span onclick="myFunction()" data-tooltip="Copy" data-tooltip-position="bottom" id="firstnamereflect">Hover Me</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Once I changed the alert to document.execCommand("copy"); it did it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Jinu!  This worked perfectly once I changed the alert to the document.execCommand("copy"); string.  Now I just need to dissect it so I can understand what you did!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("firstnamereflect").firstChild;
  var range = document.createRange();
  var endOffset = copyText.length;
  range.setStart(copyText, 0);
  range.setEnd(copyText, endOffset);
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  alert("Copied the text: " + range);
}
```

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
  padding: 4px;
}


/* Tooltip styling */

[data-tooltip]:before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


/* Dynamic horizontal centering */

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:before,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}


/* Tooltip arrow styling/placement */

[data-tooltip]:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}


/* Dynamic horizontal centering for the tooltip */

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}

[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
  top: 100%;
  border-width: 0 6px 6px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}


/* Show the tooltip when hovering */

[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  display: block;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <span onclick="myFunction()" data-tooltip="Copy" data-tooltip-position="bottom" id="firstnamereflect">Hover Me</span>
</div>
```